# create new vectors from columns of an existing matrix

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, assign

I'd like to create new vectors from columns of an existing matrix. My code looks like:

```
Matrix=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9];
A=Matrix(:,1);
B=Matrix(:,2);
C=Matrix(:,3);
```

I see that this code is not really elegant especially if I have a big number of columns, that's why I'm looking for something like:

```
[A B C]=Matrix;
```

But Matlab said the matrix can't be assigned to multiple values. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [mat2cell](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html) to split your original matrix up and [deal](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/deal.html) to assign the splitted data to the result variables A,B and C:

```
m = mat2cell(Matrix,size(Matrix,1),ones(1,size(Matrix,2)))
[A,B,C] = deal(m{:})
```

Unfortunately the intermediary variable is needed (however there is the FEX function [dealcell](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10162-dealcell) that solves this if you like one-liners)

Comment: `mat2cell` and sisters seem to be very useful to me. I'll get a deep look on them.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to do this?  (Just curious)  Matlab is designed to work off of a matrix.  Hence the name Matrix Labratory...  But alas it is still possible.

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution but I'll let you ponder that.  This should get you going.

```
Matrix=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9];

for i=1:size(Matrix,2) %number of rows
  eval(sprintf('A%d = Matrix(:,i)', i));
end
```

A1 =

```
 1
 4
 7
```

A2 =

```
 2
 5
 8
```

A3 =

```
 3
 6
 9
```

Comment: The Matrix is given in a file generated by an external server. The file contains also a lot of different data. I want to extract the 'useful' vectors and rename them so other people can understand (from the vectors names) what I'm programming.

Comment: Ok, you might also want to look into using cell arrays as a possiblity too then.

Comment: in this case, I would allow this kind of separation of variables. Op himself says the original matrix is just a lot of data thrown together in one big file

Comment: I understand that now, just didn't have that information when the question was first posed.